# Why can't we ask questions?

Tags: discussion

I was reading in a article that asked whether Mohammed was supposed to be the prophet Jesus spoke about in the Bible. I asked that question here. Someone replied that this is not the place to ask about Islam. I don’t understand why. To understand my religion and to further it, don’t I need to ask questions?

This is the time to educate ourselves, as many Christians are backsliding to the cult of Islam. If you don’t believe me, go to YouYube and see all the Christians converting to that cult. For every four we lose it seems we gain one. If we are to fight for their salvation then *all* questions should be asked, from all religions. If we do not answer the questions with which Islam attacks us, we as a religion should just start facing Mecca and praying to the pagan stone.

We must defend our faith. If we don’t do it now, when shall we do it? When we don’t know the answers any more, where can we turn? I am a Christian and I don’t know everything; I can’t remember everything; but I have enough trust in my faith to know my brothers and sisters will help me fight the satanic religion which is attacking us.

Comment: I've moved this to the META site, which is the proper venue for discussing what is and isn't on-topic for the main site.

Comment: There are some questions about mohammed that aren't closed, while others are. It's a matter of scope. The site has a specific scope that is strictly held to. The question you are referring to was probably outside of that scope.

Comment: You would need to demonstrate that there are Christians who believe that Mohammad is a prophet and then speak to that group.  This site is to ask questions about rites, rituals, and beliefs of groups claiming to be Christian.  It is not a place to ".. defend our faith.."

Comment: You spend one small paragraph asking about the policies of this site: perfectly on topic. You then spend two paragraphs ranting about perfidious Islam: absolutely off topic. Hence my downvote.

Comment: *This is the time to educate ourselves*: You're exactly right. That's why I asked this question:http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1354/1100

Comment: It's also why I asked this question:http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4070/1100

Answer (score 8):

I understand your concern; but this site is intended to be a source of questions and answers about Christian teachings, practices, and history. Most questions (not all) involving Mohammed are likely not to fall into these categories.

Answer (score 5):

Questions about Islam should go to the [Q&A site for Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/). Often times, keeping on-topic is merely a matter of wording.

The [site tour](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) defines what is on topic as

- the history of denominations (such as Roman Catholic, Anglican, Church of Christ, or the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints) and movements (such as Pentecostalism, Creationism, Calvinism)
- understanding the Bible from the perspective of a specific viewpoint (like those listed above)
- explanations of the beliefs and practices of a denomination or movement
- the Biblical basis for a belief or practice

So if, For example if you asked "what is the biblical basis for the claim that the prophet Jesus spoke of was ____" (I'm not aware of any passage where jesus spoke of a coming prophet, so I can't fill in that blank) or "what is the biblical basis for the belief there will be no future prophets" these might be on topic. Conversely, several things are off topic:

- a survey of all Christian views on a particular subject
- what the Bible says about a subject (unless you specify a doctrine/tradition)
- advice on how to handle certain situations (pastoral advice questions)
- is "X" a sin questions that ask whether a certain action or belief is sinful
- "Truth" questions that do not focus on what a specific group of people teaches
  whether some group or person is "Christian"

So, if you asked "What should I tell my islamic friend who thinks that Jesus spoke of a coming prophet?" or "What does the bible say about islam?" these would be off-topic.